# Accessing class labels in ARFF

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to learn Weka: I am using  Iris data set  from here 
http://storm.cis.fordham.edu/~gweiss/data-mining/weka-data/iris.arff

which has following fields

```
@RELATION iris

@ATTRIBUTE sepallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE sepalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}
```

From this dataset I am trying extract the class labels from this data set, which is {I**ris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}**

I am not understanding how to get the class labels? Any references

```
   public  void getCdtion( String arff_path) throws Exception{

    ArffLoader arffloder = new ArffLoader();
    arffloder.setFile(new File(arff_path));
    arffloder.getStructure();
    Instances structure = arffloder.getDataSet();



    System.out.println(arffloder.getStructure(););

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `arffloader.getDataSet()` which returns the data set, not the header. The ARFF you provide in your question is just a header with no data in it. To get the class labels from the header, do the following.

```
public  void getCdtion( String arff_path) throws Exception{

    ArffLoader arffloder = new ArffLoader();
    arffloder.setFile(new File(arff_path));
    Instances structure = arffloder.getStructure();
    Attribute classAtt = structure.classAttribute();

    System.out.println(classAtt);

}
```

The class attribute `classAtt` is an [Attribute](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Attribute.html), see the link for more info.
Hope it helps!